# Javascript create input field using a select element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple website that calculates a card game score. The website will prompt a user to enter the number of players and return that number of fields for name inputs.

However, as my code stands currently, when a user enters the number of players, the website only shows one field for maybe a second and disappears. I was hoping that someone could help me (a novice programmer) on how to create input text fields dynamically with Javascript. Thanks!

```js
//*****script.js*****


  let response = parseInt(document.getElementById("players").value);

const playerNames = () => {

  let player;
  for (let i = 0; i < response; i++) {
    player = document.createElement('input');
    player.type = 'text';
    document.body.appendChild(player);
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="start" action="index.html" method="post">
      <p>How many players?</p>
      <select id="players" class="" name="">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="playerNames()"/>

    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use [event.PreventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in your function.

Comment: Put let `response` inside your function `playerName`

Comment: Replace your function to this `const playerNames = (e) => {
  let response = parseInt(document.getElementById("players").value);
  e.preventDefault()
  let player;
  for (let i = 0; i < response; i++) {
    player = document.createElement('input');
    player.type = 'text';
    document.body.appendChild(player);
  };
}`

Comment: Replace your submit button to this : `<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="playerNames(event)"/>
`

Comment: Everything will work fine.

Comment: The problems is that you are usin FORM post method. Javascript execute fine But form reload the page again. The second point is that the line:  let response = parseInt(document.getElementById("players").value); should be inside the function.

Comment: I'm sure you're learning things about form controls, but things are different when everything is taking place just in the page itself. Since you are not planning to submit this data to a server to process, there is no reason to use a `<form>` (as 95faf8e76605e973 says) and no reason to have an `<input type="submit">` either. As others have said, the reason the fields show then disappear immediately is because the page reloads due to the form `POST` action. You can use a `<button type="button">Submit</button>` with a click-handler on that. (I'd use some word instead of "Submit" too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not wrap your fields in a `<form>`. If you do this, since your button is type of submit: by default your browser will attempt to submit the form to another page & redirect. You can simply use `<div>` as a wrapper. Once you do this, you can remove the HTML attributes `action` & `method` since these attributes are no longer essential to your code base as you are no longer submitting a form.

As for the script, simply move the gathering of the input inside of the function not outside. So onclick event, that is the time you get the input from the `<select>`

```html
<body>
  <div class="start">
    <p>How many players?</p>
    <select id="players" class="" name="">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="playerNames()">Submit</button>

  </div>
  <script>
    //*****script.js*****
    const playerNames = () => {
      let response = parseInt(document.getElementById("players").value);
      let player;
      for (let i = 0; i < response; i++) {
        player = document.createElement('input');
        player.type = 'text';
        document.body.appendChild(player);
      };
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Still wrong. This will reload the page. Read the comments as well before answering.

Comment: It will not "reload the page". Run the code & check your network tab. No request is going to be made. Run the code as well before commenting.

Comment: You're getting rid of the form (changing to a div) you should remove the `action=` and `method=` also. They're distracting and made me miss the form element was changed, even though you mentioned it in your answer text.

Comment: @StephenP Agree. This is not what OP wanted. This is NOT a good answer at all. HTML is changed to a div where in the question does OP said so and wanted that ? Hence why i downvoted.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 why would you change a `form` to a `div` just to avoid reloading the page which i highlighted in my first comment. Please fix your answer.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 `type=submit` is not needed as well. Just a simple `button` would do that job too.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 Keep editing - Just a simple button not an input button. Atleast you are learning something.

Comment: It is simply a variation of an answer. There are multiple ways of solving this ;)

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 Multiple ways BUT and needs to effective and you must have to follow good coding practice as well. You answer will help others too not just this question.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 See that was easy. I appreciate your answer now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the action takes hold and index.html is loaded.  Use event.preventDefault() to stop this load.  place response inside the function so each time submit is pressed it captures the value of the select box

```js
//*****script.js*****



const playerNames = () => {
event.preventDefault();

let response = parseInt(document.getElementById("players").value);

  let player;
  for (let i = 0; i < response; i++) {
    player = document.createElement('input');
    player.type = 'text';
    document.body.appendChild(player);
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="start" action="index.html" method="post">
      <p>How many players?</p>
      <select id="players" class="" name="">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="playerNames()"/>

    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An answer should not be code only - Read the comments as well before answering. this is already answered.